# Python project in visual studio deployed on AWS using lambda?

Tags: python, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda

I have a python project with a lot of dependencies (around 30 or so python packages) that i want to deploy on aws using lambda function. Right now i have about 30 custom python packages in my VS solution that i import into the main function - there is a lot of code. What is the best way to build a deployment package and how would i go about doing this?

I watched a few tutorials but i am new to this, so im not sure exactly what concrete steps to take. If i use something like zappa and create a virtual environment how would i then get my project there and install all the dependencies and then zip the file?

Thanks so much, sorry for the stupid questions, i couldn't find a stackoverflow post that covered this

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your python environment folder and found `site-package` folder (usually in `/lib`), choose all the dependencies you need and zip them with your code.

I guess it's the easiest way.

[image]

For example, I may need `beautifulsoup` and `urllib` for dependencies, just zip them (and their dependencies, if needed) with my code, then upload to AWS Lambda, that's all.

[image]

BTW, you can also see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/4a052f39490fae00e0c3) to know whether the module you need can be directly import to AWS Lambda or not.